# What does all this mean?

Tags: power-supply, power

So, I got all this off of an HP power supply and would like to know what it means.

```
INPUT(Chinese): 100V ~/10A
OUTPUT(Chineese):800W(MAX.)
    +12.15V  (Power Symbol)   /65.8A MAX.    +5VSB   (Power Symbol)   /2A MAX.
    +3.3VSB   (Power Symbol)   /8A MAX.   -12V   (Power Symbol)          /0.3A MAX.
INPUT(Chinese):110 - 120V ~ / 10A
OUTPUT(Chinese): 850W(MAX.)
+12.15V   (Power Symbol)   /69.9A MAX.    +5VSB (Power Symbol) /2A MAX.
+3.3VSB   (Power Symbol) /8A MAX.           -12V (Power Symbol)    /0.3A MAX.
INPUT(Chinese): 200-240V ~ /6.7A
OUTPUT(Chinese): 1000W(MAX.)
   +12.15V   (Power Symbol)   /82.3A MAX.   +5VSB (Power Symbol) /2A MAX.
   +3.3VSB   (Power Symbol)  /8A MAX.            -12V (Power Symbol) /0.3A MAX.
```

So, if I put in 122 Volts and 15 Amps for it, how many watts will I get?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What means what? These are specs for the power supply. And yes, you can perfectly format here.

Comment: Now that @EugeneSh. fixed the formatting, it seems pretty clear what it means. The input current depends on voltage. And the maximum power output varies somewhat with different input voltages. Please show some respect for other people's time by asking a more specific question.

Comment: V = volts, A = Amps   W (Watts) is a measurement of power  , + is positive,  - is negative,  MAX is an an abbreviation of maximum, INPUT is what you put in and OUTPUT is what you get out and your question is?

Comment: A photo would have been better - I can't believe "Chinese" is spelt two different ways.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be telling you what the supply can do for three different input power voltages.  I'm not sure what "Chinese" is supposed to tell you, but that would mean 50 Hz is assumed.

The first section tells you the supply can put out 800 W with 100 V in, the second section 850 W out with 110-120 V in, and the third section 1 kW with 200-240 W in.

Comment: I would guess that (Chinese) means that there is some text in Chinese characters at that location. Based on the locations, I am sure the Chinese text must mean "input" and "output." The OP could figure this out to a high degree of certainty if the characters after "input" are always the same, and the characters after "output" are always the same, but are different from the characters after "input."

Comment: "SB" in this context may refer to "slow-blow" which is a particular type of fuse.  So some of the nomenclature may be referring to the appropriate fuse ratings for the various outputs.

Comment: @RichardCrowley : more likely "SB" refers to the Standby supplies.

Comment: @Brian Drummond, yes, that makes more sense, at least with the  minimal contextual information we have available.